# EsLint-plugin-import/order - Created pathGroups don't work. Problems with pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, eslint

I have imports like 'types/' and './types/'. And I want to see them in one pathGroup. But any pattern doesn't work.
I tried:

```
{types/** | ./types}
{types/** , ./types}
(types/** | ./types)
{types/** , ./types/**}
"** /types/ **"
```

Is it possible?